# Why is this many-to-many relation changing whitout me asking for it, using the Django ORM?

Tags: django, orm, many-to-many

I have a recursive M2M relationship with an indicator class. An indicator is a int, or a calculated value from 2 indicators:

```
class Indicator(models.Model):


    params = models.ManyToManyField('self', 
                                verbose_name=__(u'parameters'),
                                related_name='params_of', 
                                blank=True, null=True)

    type = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name=__(u'type'))

    def get_value(self, record):

        # etc
```

According to the type, get_value doesn't do the same things. It can just return the numerical value or calculate a value from the numerical value of each parameters from the `params` attribute. As you can see `params` is a recursive m2m relationship.

Now my problem is that, I have the follwoing indicators:

- men
- women
- total pop
- men ratio

If I add `men` and `women` as parameters of `total pop`, everything is fine, and I get my total pop dynamically calculated. But if I then add `men` and `total pop` as parameters to `men ratio`, **then `total pop` automatically get `men ratio` as a parameter.** It breaks everything.

Why is that? How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

M2M relations in Django are symmetric by default ie in an M2M, if a related to b then b also related to a. To stop this, use `symmetrical=False`

your params would become:

```
params = models.ManyToManyField('self', 
                                verbose_name=__(u'parameters'),
                                related_name='params_of', 
                                blank=True, null=True,
                                symmetrical=False)
```